# Express middleware in Express (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, middleware

I'm rewriting the backend of an ExpressJS application into Typescript. In auth.routes.ts, I encountered an error related to middleware(authMiddleware). As I understand it, there is a typing error, because the same file in the js extension works fine.

Please help me figure this out.

Below is the corresponding code

---

auth.routes.ts

```
import { Router } from "express"
import authMiddleware from "../middleware/auth.middleware"
import authController from "../controllers/authController"

const router = Router()

router.get("/", authMiddleware, authController.auth)

export default router
```

---

auth.middleware.ts

```
import "dotenv/config"
import { NextFunction, Response } from "express"
import jwt, { JwtPayload, Secret } from "jsonwebtoken"
import { CustomHeaders } from "../models"

const secretKey: Secret = process.env.secretKey as Secret

interface AuthRequest extends Request {
  user?: JwtPayload
}

function authMiddleware(req: AuthRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    next()
  }

  try {
    const token = (req.headers as CustomHeaders).authorization?.split(" ")[1]

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" })
    }
    const decoded: JwtPayload = jwt.verify(token!, secretKey) as JwtPayload
    req.user = decoded

    next()
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Bad Request" })
  }
}

export default authMiddleware
```

---

Error description:

> No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: AuthRequest, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
> Type '(req: AuthRequest, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
> Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
> Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'AuthRequest': cache, credentials, destination, integrity, and 13 more.ts(2769)

I tried to ask chatGPT about my problem, but I also received non-working variationss

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      email: string
      password: string
      user?: JwtPayload
    }
  }
}
```